# How to set button unvisible when timer count === 0 in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React.js and I have a question.

I want to send a feedback by button click. It is sending via `axios` request with timeout 3 seconds.

I put `Cancel` button if user wants to cancel sending feedback for this timeout (3 seconds) - (and `axios` request is being cancelled as well).

Then, I put timer on button, but it is situated under text even I use `<span>`. I attached code to **[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-mendeleev-7m7e3)**. Now it is test mode, just need to fix:

- time above text - it needs to be in left of the text.
- cancel function is also received wrongly as a props because of console messages (it doesn't cancel parent's state).
- I need `Cancel` button to be show to 0 count, so I need to unmount button when it is 0 and hide it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like this?? https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-heyrovsky-inec5

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes! but I look at my code and can't see what lines are changed

Comment: I have added as an answer mentioning what changes I have did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two make two changes here,

**1)** In `send.js` file make changes in following under `sendApi()` method,

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: false
  });
  console.log("Ok");
}, 4000);
```

As the cancel button is populated only when `isLoading` is true, you can make it to false inside `sendApi()` method after the `setTimeout` to remove it after the given time.

**2)** To make the timer count and cancel text to stay in line of the button,

Under `timer.js` change the return statement under `render()` method like,

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>{count}</React.Fragment>
);
```

> [**Forked sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-heyrovsky-inec5)

Comment: it works great, but when i want to cancel before time is ended, it gives an error

Comment: @RobertGurjiev, Here you go.. https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-flower-8vljn  .. That issue happens because there is no reference to ```this``` keyword so you need to make arrow function for ```onClick``` in cancel button.. Also you need to make change in timer.js file under ```this.myInterval = setInterval(() ... )``` which you could see in the sandbox..

Comment: and how to stop counting when it reaches to '0'? just for intereset :)

Comment: @RobertGurjiev, That is what actually happens in the latest sandbox provided in above comment.. In timer.js file inside setInterval, this line does that ```count:
          prevState.count > 0
            ? prevState.count - 1
            : clearInterval(this.myInterval)``` .. The count will happen only if it is greater than 0 else clear all interval..

Answer (score 1):

```
  doIntervalChange = () => {
    if (this.state.count === 0) {
      this.hide();
    }
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          count: prevState.count - 1
        }),
        () => {
          if (this.state.count === 0) this.hide();
        }
      );
    }, 1000);
  };
```

doIntervalChange just run 1 time when you place it in comp did mount , try this code :D

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-fire-vnq61 you can see this one here

Comment: could you also see line EDITED here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60999179/11699467