# How to resolve React.js states with multiple button clicks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I attached code in **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-fog-2m34u)** and video on **[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yODcFv08-E&feature=youtu.be)**. You can see what actualy goes on when multiple clicks are made in short time. So, I tried a lot, but nothing happened.

So, the issues are:

- when click miltiple times 'Send message' - 'Cancel', application remembers previous click and hides 'Cancel' button soon;
- the same happens to bottom message with when feedback message is not sent.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDITED**:

also I need to situate alerts one one line with buttons. no span, no  helps

[image]

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ZombieChowder when you click multiple times to buttons, states are working wrong. I need them to work fine. Check the video and codesandbox yourself, you can see what is going on

Comment: Right away in `feedback-send.js` I saw this line of code `this.state.i += 1;` and looked no further. Direct state manipulations are a react anti-pattern.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry I am Java developer, haven't learned React.js well yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways to solve this... What I have done in the past is pretty much give an id to each API call and then when it comes back check to make sure that is the current id of the api call. Something like this:

```js
sendApi() {
    const currentCallId = uuid() // Or some random id generator
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
      invalidFeedback: false,
      showTimer: true,
      inputDisabled: true,
      currentCallId
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (currentCallId !== this.state.currentCallId) return //Ignore
      if (this.state.isLoading && this.state.showTimer) {
        this.setState({
          showTimer: false
        });
      }
    }, 4000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (currentCallId !== this.state.currentCallId) return //Ignore
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        Api.post("feedback/add", {
          id: this.props.id, // ?????????
          description: this.state.description
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (currentCallId !== this.state.currentCallId) return //Ignore
            if (this.state.isLoading) {
              response.status === 201 // ?????????????
                ? this.showFeedbackSent()
                : this.showFeedbackNotSent();
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(error);
          })
          .then(() =>{
            if (currentCallId !== this.state.currentCallId) return //Ignore
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, inputDisabled: false })
          });
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You helped!

one more question. how to make my counter not to mount after it becomes '0'?

Comment: also how to show alerts in one line with 'Send message' button? for example, "Feedback must be more than 9 symbols" if user want to send (it is in code)

Comment: For the first one... just do a check on the state in your timer. If it is 1, you know the next is going to be zero. So call hide (instead of waiting for it to hit zero to call hide). I am not sure what you mean by show alerts in one line. Like for the UI. You just need to update the css.

Comment: i've edited post. you can see what i mean, it shouldn't be connected with styles

Answer (score 1):

You will need a clearTimeout call somewhere. When you call setTimeout you can store the returned value as a property of the class (or as state), for example

```
this.timer = setTimeout(() => { .... }, 4000)
```

Then in the cancel method you can kill timer like so:

```
clearTimeout(this.timer)
```

Looks to me as though you have more timers than necessary ... I think just one will be sufficient here.